# how to use a link to download a file in php

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code to fill the drop-down box and select a file and download it. Its working perfect.But i tried using every file to display as link and download it on clicking the link.

```
echo "<form id=\"form\" name=\"psform\" action=\"download_logic.php\" method=\"post\"><label>Select File:&nbsp</label><select name=\"file\" >";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             echo "<option  value='" . $row['location'] . "'>"  . $row['location'] . "</option>";
            }

            echo "</select></label>";
        echo"<br>";
            echo "<input id=\"submit\" type=\"submit\"  name=\"filesubmit\" value=\"Download\" />  </form>";
```

its giving me errors ....any help please....

I am using following code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<a  href=\"download_logic.php?f=\". $row['location'] .\". $row['fileshare'] .\">"  . $row['fileshare'] . "</a>";

}
```

Here is the error in the `<a>` tag*** Error (unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)***

Comment: **"its giving me errors"** and they are?

Comment: post us the errors and the whole script please because this is not enough to debug or solve your problem...

Comment: **The errors.** Tell them us.

Comment: am not sure of the way to do that, but i am trying the above way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
echo '<a  href="download_logic.php?f='. $row['location'] .'/'. $row['fileshare'] .'">'  . $row['fileshare'] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry I can't tell you why it happens, but if you change all of the **\"** to **'** it should work for you.

```
echo "<form id='form' name='psform' action='download_logic.php' method='post'><label>Select File:&nbsp</label><select name='file' >";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             echo "<option  value='" . $row['location'] . "'>"  . $row['location'] . "</option>";
            }

            echo "</select></label>";
        echo"<br>";
            echo "<input id='submit' type='submit'  name='filesubmit' value='Download' />  </form>";
```

As for the next part, you can't add a variable to a string just by writing

```
"variable: . $take['variable']"
```

If you wish to add variables to string close the writen part of the string and then add the variable, like this:

```
"variable: ". $take['variable']
```

Here is how it sould look like:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<a  href='download_logic.php?f=". $row['location'] . $row['fileshare'] ."'>"  . $row['fileshare'] . "</a>";

}
```